# Concatenating two identical dataframes and only keeping the new entries

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes which are identical asides from an extra row or two. How do I concatenate them together into one dataframe but only add on the new entries to the original dataframe?

I have tried using pandas to do this but I can only concatenate them together I can't figure out a way to only keep the new entries and have them added onto the original.

Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can `concat` and `drop_duplicates`

```
dfnew = pd.concat([df1,df2])
dfnew.drop_duplicates(inplace=True,keep=False)
```